# Set variable as file name

Tags: php, file

I need set variable as file name

```
$file = fopen("\acc\'<?php echo '$nickname''.ucg", "a+");
```

but file saved as `<?php echo '$nickname''.ucg` :/ i need for example myname.ucg (myname = variable $nickname)

Comment: just `$file = fopen("\acc\$nickname.ucg", "a+");`

Comment: You already have PHP tags open, so there's no need to reopen them. You should read about [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// for example
$nickname = 'johnson';
$file = fopen('./login/'.$nickname.'.ucg', 'a+');
```

Comment: web not work with this code

Comment: @Lexikonn sorry about that, I copied your code with the '\' for the folder paths while this '/' is correct. I fixed it now. Should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanx it work! :)